# Sign my android project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, code-signing, android-keystore

I want to sign my android project using eclipse with a debug keystore file and be able to run the project on my emulator directly by clicking the Run button on eclipse ide. I have read the tutorial to export the apk from eclipse and sign it with a keystore file and then using the adb command line I can run that apk to my android emulator. But is it possible to directly just run the project from eclipse and somehow it should sign the application with the keystore file?

Comment: Try use Ant for sign yuor app with your keystore file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But is it possible to directly just run the project from eclipse and somehow it should sign the application with the keystore file?

Eclipse will automatically sign your app with the debug signing key when you run it from the IDE. No additional configuration is necessary

> I want to sign my android project using eclipse with a debug keystore file and be able to run the project on my emulator directly by clicking the Run button on eclipse ide.

That is how Eclipse works when it is installed.

Comment: I have a custom debug keystore file, provided by my employer, which I'll have to mention somewhere in the eclipse project settings for it to sign my application with that file before running it on emulator.
How is it possible without specifying the debug keystore file?

Comment: By the way I have tried this - There is certain feature that works only when the application is signed with that keystore file. When I directly run the app from eclipse on my emulator, the feature doesn't work. But when I export the application and sign it with my keystore file, and then install the signed apk on my emulator, the feature works fine.

Comment: @Him: "I have a custom debug keystore file, provided by my employer" -- copy it to the proper spot on your development machine, replacing the generated `debug.keystore` file. On OS X or Linux, this would be in `~/.android`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

As CommonsWare said eclipse automatically sign application using default keystore. If you wants to export your project for release (want to sign using your keysotre ) then follow these steps:
1. **Right click on project -> Android Tools-> Export Signed Application Package**
[image]

Then click on **Next** in popup window. Now it will ask for keystore. Select **use existing** if you wants to use exiting keystore and **Browse** to select file and **fill password**. Also you can create a new one by selecting **Create new keysore** fill all required information then click "Next". 
Then give out file path and name, click on **Finish**. All done. You will get your file soon at selected path.

Comment: This is standart way to create signed app, but this is not 'one click' solution...